# Responsive CSS not working is Ultimo Magento theme

Tags: magento

I am facing unusual error. I am using Ultimo theme in magento but the CSS is not changing up according to device width. 
Here is my website : http://www.jakartatas.net/.
I am using Magento version 1.5
I tried all the option by merging CSS, Enabled Responsive Layout. Still the problem remains. 
Please Help me.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like the default responsive CSS is loading OK, just needs tidying up

Comment: @WombleGold, Please guide me, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin->system->configuration->generat->design->themes tab and add ultimo to all field of themes  like template,skin,layout,default etc and save.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in "head.phtml file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```